# Jenkins-Weblogic 12c: How to start Nodemanager with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

I have installed Jenkins.
With a 'Execute shell' Build i am trying to do the following in order to start ./startNodemanager:

```
cd /home/aram/wblogic_12C/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/bin
./startNodeManager.sh > /home/aram/Documents/null 2>&1 &
./startWebLogic.sh > /home/aram/Documents/null 2>&1 &
```

Jenkins returns the following error:

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/StartSOAEnv
[StartSOAEnv] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2590954594213459476.sh
+ cd /home/aram/weblogic_12C/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/bin
/tmp/hudson2590954594213459476.sh: line 2: cd: /home/aram/weblogic_12C/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/bin: Not a directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Has some one had the same issue? How can i reach the ./startNodemanager Script

Comment: Should it really be `wblogic_12C` or perhaps `weblogic_12C` in your path? Error says it can't find the folder, not that it can't start the `nodeManager`

Comment: @radimpe is right ... check again that you have given the correct directory structure and that there are noo typos

Comment: the directory is correct. It has something to do with permissions. If i try to navigate to ~/ then it tells me that i have no permission for that. I need to configure somehow SUDO command in Jenkins.

Comment: Are you starting your jenkins client as the user aram? If not you might want to.

Comment: yes, tnx. As you said the issue acquired due to roots permissions.